# calling a defined function after jquery click() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, user-defined-functions

Please consider the following script block. Problem is explained as comments.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function changeMenu(e) {
        $('#navigator').removeClass('a').removeClass('b').addClass(e);
    };

    // Neither this line
    changeMenu('element-id');

    $('.mainmenuitem').click(
        // Nor this line execute the function
        changeMenu(this.id)
    );

})
```

Note that if I put the code `$('#nav').removeClass('a').removeClass('b').addClass(e);` out of function, and use this in the 2 places that `changeMenu()` has been called, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax errors, you need to close your functions, or in this case, add functions to the event handlers :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function changeMenu(selectedMenuID) {
        $('#navigator').removeClass('a b').addClass(selectedMenuID);
    }

    changeMenu('parse-gallery');

    $('.mainmenuitem').click(function() {
        changeMenu(this.id)
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDXTk/1/)

Comment: I should also thank for teaching me how to remove 2 classes at once! `:D`

Answer (score 1):

Please check what you have missed in your code..

```
$('.mainmenuitem').click(function(){
        changeMenu(this.id)
});
```